# How do I see absolute time stamps in Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump

There is an example of `pcap` file opened in `wireshark`
[image]

The second column is time. Is it possible to see absolute timestamps here instead of relative?

Comment: In the `View` menu click `Time Display Format` and choose one of the `Time of Day` options. (The file is already fine.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Could you please submit your comment as an answer?  It's the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(from comment)

A pcap file (from tcpdump *or* wireshark or AFAIK anything else using libpcap) already has absolute time; it's only the **Wireshark display** you need to adjust.

In the `View` menu click `Time Display Format` and choose one of the `Time of Day` options.

Answer (score 2):

tcpdump has its own timestump options for.

```
-t
    Don't print a timestamp on each dump line. 
-tt
    Print the timestamp, as seconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00, UTC, and fractions of a second since that time, on each dump line. 
-ttt
    Print a delta (micro-second resolution) between current and previous line on each dump line. 
-tttt
    Print a timestamp, as hours, minutes, seconds, and fractions of a second since midnight, preceded by the date, on each dump line. 
-ttttt
    Print a delta (micro-second resolution) between current and first line on each dump line.
```

More info you can find at tcpdump [manpage](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html).